# Combine variant and build type in dependency implementation

Tags: android, gradle, build-variant

I need to implement variant-specific libraries im my project, lets say i have:

```
flavorDimensions "dimensionOne", "dimensionTwo"

productFlavors {
    dimensionOneVariantOne {
        dimension "dimensionOne"
    }
    dimensionOneVariantTwo {
        dimension "dimensionOne"
    }
    dimensionTwoVariantOne {
        dimension "dimensionTwo"
    }
    dimensionTwoVariantTwo {
        dimension "dimensionTwo"
    }
}
```

and in dependency implementation, i need to use, for example

```
dimensionTwoVariantOneDebugImplementation("maven-library:version")
dimensionTwoVariantOneReleaseImplementation("maven-library:version")
```

I thought that was the correct syntax, but somewhy I'm not able to do that, I get a
"Could not find method dimensionTwoVariantOneDebugImplementation() for arguments " error.

I defined two flavorDimensions because thats what I have in my real project, and the first one is not relevant for the implementation on that library.
But I also tried including it with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Edit

Adding only one configuration wasn't enough, I had to add the full combinations in both configuration and dependency implementation, like

```
configurations{
  dimensionOneVariantOneDimensionTwoVariantOneDebugImplementation
  dimensionOneVariantOneDimensionTwoVariantOneReleaseImplementation
  dimensionOneVariantTwoDimensionTwoVariantOneDebugImplementation
  dimensionOneVariantTwoDimensionTwoVariantOneReleaseImplementation
}
```

and the respective implementation blocks

---

Apparently, all i needed was

```
configurations{
    dimensionTwoVariantOneDebugImplementation
}
```

I'm not sure tho if not adding the other variants will have any impact